# Failed to execute 'createBuffer' on 'BaseAudioContext'

Tags: typescript, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

> Failed to execute 'createBuffer' on 'BaseAudioContext': The number of
>   frames provided (0) is less than or equal to the minimum bound (0)."

My project attempts to create an audiobuffer for a Float32Array stream chunk.

***initialization of audiocontext***

```
  constructor(loading: LoadingService) {
  ... 
    this.audiocontext = new audiocontext()
  ...
  }
```

***creation of audio buffer***

```
private onmusicdownloaded = (response: streamresponse) => {  
    if(response.totalchunks !== 0 &&
      isnullorundefined(this.buffers)) {
      this.buffers = new Array<AudioBuffer>(response.totalchunks) //lets me make correct playback decisions
    }     
    console.log('stream chunk received')   
    this.currentbufferdownloaded++
    let rawbuffer = new Float32Array(response.chunk)
    let newbuffer = this.audiocontext.createBuffer(1, rawbuffer.length, 44100)

    newbuffer.getChannelData(0)
      .set(rawbuffer)
    this.buffers[this.currentbufferdownloaded] = newbuffer
    this.currentbufferdownloaded++

    if(this.musicisreadytoplay() === false) {
      return
    }
    this.playrandomdeserttrack()
  }
```

It fails at the source line where the `newbuffer` variable is defined. I dont understand how I can "provide frames" without creating the buffer first.

[link to full file](https://github.com/DoubleCouponDay/portfolio/blob/master/client/src/app/services/music.service.ts)

All solution thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: "number of frames" --> second params of `createBuffer(numOfchannels, length, sampleRate);`. Your `rawbuffer` is an empty Float32Arrray, either because `response.chunk` is an empty ArrayBuffer, either because it is not an ArrayBuffer.

Comment: @Kaiido correct! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kaiido It's embarrassing but that was the right answer! I need to remember to always check my assumptions.

[image]